# How to change Flutter Bloc state for a Category Selection?

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management, mobile-development

I am just starting with Flutter.

I want to change the selected category in a list by changing the color when a user taps on the category.

I have the UI build function like this

```
Widget _buildCategories() {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 110,
      child: BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is CategoriesLoaded) {
            final categories = state.categories;
            final selectedCategory = state.selectedCategory;
            return ListView.separated(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    context.read<HomeBloc>().add(
                        UpdateSelectedCategory(category: categories[index]));
                  },
                  child: CategoryCell(
                      category: categories[index],
                      isSelected: selectedCategory == categories[index]),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const SizedBox(width: 16);
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const Text('err');
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

And here I have the three Bloc related classes

```
class HomeBloc extends Bloc<HomeEvent, HomeState> {
  final CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

  HomeBloc({
    required this.categoryRepository,
  }) : super(HomeInitial()) {
    on<LoadCategories>(_loadCategories);
    on<UpdateSelectedCategory>(_updateSelectedCategory);
  }

  _loadCategories(LoadCategories event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
    emit(CategoriesLoading());

    final categories = categoryRepository.fetchCategories();
    emit(CategoriesLoaded(
        categories: categories, selectedCategory: categories.first));
  }

  void _updateSelectedCategory(
      UpdateSelectedCategory event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
    final updatedState = event.category;
    emit((state as CategoriesLoaded)
        .copyWith(selectedCategory: updatedState));
  }
}
```

```
sealed class HomeEvent extends Equatable {
  const HomeEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadCategories extends HomeEvent {}


final class UpdateSelectedCategory extends HomeEvent {
  final BrochureCategory category;

  const UpdateSelectedCategory({required this.category});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [category];
}
```

```
sealed class HomeState extends Equatable {
  const HomeState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class HomeInitial extends HomeState {}

final class CategoriesLoading extends HomeState {}

final class CategoriesLoaded extends HomeState {
  final List<BrochureCategory> categories;
  final BrochureCategory selectedCategory;
  const CategoriesLoaded(
      {required this.selectedCategory, required this.categories});

   CategoriesLoaded copyWith({
    List<BrochureCategory>? categories,
    BrochureCategory? selectedCategory,
  }) {
    return CategoriesLoaded(
      selectedCategory: selectedCategory ?? this.selectedCategory,
      categories: categories ?? this.categories,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [categories, selectedCategory];
}
```

I am not sure if this CategoriesLoaded state should also hold the state of the Category selection
But if I create another state like CategorySelectionUpdated then I can't have acces to it in the UI part.

Also in my beginner view this code does not seem efficient.

```
 void _updateSelectedCategory(
      UpdateSelectedCategory event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) {
    final updatedState = event.category;
    emit((state as CategoriesLoaded)
        .copyWith(selectedCategory: updatedState));
  }
}
```

Is this a good Approach with Bloc or can it be done with Cubit for me to better understand the concept?

I tried to load the categories and also to update the selection of the category based on a user's tap.